# fork() why not infinite output

Tags: c, process, fork

why does

```
int main(...) {  
    fork();  
    printf("hello again\n");  
    exit(0);  
}
```

not create an infinte number of processess?
I understood it as follows, the main process creates a childprocess, the child an other child, and so on.

Comment: You have to put `fork()` in an infinite loop in order to get infinite forks.

Comment: @HristoIliev Although the loop can be implicit .. imagine an `exec` above the `exit`.

Comment: try this: int main() {fork();main();}

Comment: @pst, on a second thought, the OP probably thinks that `fork()` starts the executable from the beginning, i.e. something like `if (!fork()) { execl(argv[0],argv[0],NULL); }`

Comment: i dont want to have a infinite loop, i only did not understood why this is not a infinite loop. by not its clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The execution continues after the fork in both the parent and the child, it doesn't restart the program.

Comment: Now, if there was a subsequent `exec` :D

Comment: ah i when i read everywhere taht the entire process i cloned, i assumend that the parent is cloned and starts at the begining.

Comment: That wouldn't be cloning the whole process. A process knows where it's currently at, code wise, so that gets cloned as well. It really just takes the whole parent process, copies everything into a new process; both processes will be at the same state the moment the child is forked.

Comment: @user1324258 when the entire process is cloned, so the process's stack, execution context, instruction pointer, etc is cloned as well. All that defines the the state of a running process, so the forked child will have the same state as the parent, after the call to fork(). just some background info :)

Answer (score 3):

The parent process is "cloned" right at the execution point where `fork()` is called, and both processes proceed from there.  The child process doesn't start over by calling main() again.